# redirect to another page in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to redirect in page post_list but it is redirect to the same page.

```
def registration(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        print request.POST
        print form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('site1/post_list/')
    else:
        form= MyRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: are you sure your form is valid?

Comment: if not then give  the `else` to form and `print form.errors` let's what's in there ?

Comment: Yes form is valid. Problem Solved